Postgres password length limitation on POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE with docker compose
I've been playing around with docker compose trying to deploy a simple web app project, that would also use Postgres as a DB.
I've suddenly noticed that when I changed the password in my db_password.txt file to be a bit longer, my application (Next.js for context) decided that the authentication credentials were wrong even though I updated them in the database url and restarted (yes deleted old image and volume) the db container.
The auth error was as follows:
Authentication failed against database server at `localhost`, the provided database credentials for `postgres` are not valid.

Now I was using prisma as my ORM of choice, but I don't think that was the problem. While testing I found that the breaking point of password length was >21 chars (with 21 still working).
My question is as follows, has anyone ever ran into the same issue? Are there some postgres or maybe even docker compose (or even prisma) docs anywhere that mention this limitation?
This was my docker-compose.yml (for context):
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_password
    secrets:
      - db_password
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./prisma/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

volumes:
  pgdata:

secrets:
  db_password:
    file: prisma/db_password.txt

EDIT 1:
I'm also adding the prisma schema file for context, since this seems to not be a problem with docker compose or postgres itself:
schema.prisma
datasource db {
    provider = "postgresql"
    url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
    provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

The complete stack also contains Nextjs 14 with TS.

passwords can be much longer than only 21 characters. Just tested with 128 characters, using psql and scram-sha-256, and that works fine

Maybe there was a problem with the auth password algorithm, although mine was also set to scram-sha-256, not md5 or other... Weird bug...

Do you have special characters in that password like quote, at sign, ampersand, ...?

Your docker file works fine for me with a 30-character password.  Your docker file contains no actual test, so I connected from the docker host, using psql -h localhost -U postgres and it worked.  Maybe the problem is on the prisma side, but you didn't show any code related to that.

Hey maybe, will update the code, although there is not much to be seen. It's also maybe worth mentioning that I am working on an arm chip environment (MacOs M3 Pro)
